# Easier proof that the Grassmannian is a complex manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, grassmannian, complex-manifolds

> $G_r(\mathbb C^3,2)$ is the topological space of 2-dimensional complex linear subspaces of $\mathbb C^3$. Prove that $G_r(\mathbb C^3,2)$ is a complex manifold.

I have a solution to this problem, but I am wondering is there any easier way to prove this.

Solution:[image]

Second part:

[image]

Comment: Very likely no. This is as easy as it can get.

Comment: Does the following not work: Given any $L \subset G(n,k)$, choose a transversal subspace $M$ and let $\mathrm{Hom}(L, M)$ be the space of linear maps. For each $A \in \mathrm{Hom}(L,M)$, let $g_A \in G(n,k)$ be the graph of $A$, i.e., $g_A = \{ v + Av\ :\ v \in L\}$. The map $A \mapsto g_A$ is a coordinate chart containing $L$. Therefore, all such coordinate charts cover $G(n,k)$. Given any $L_1, L_2 \in G(n,k)$ that are both transversal to $M$, the coordinate charts have nonzero intersection. The transition map is analytic, since it's defined using complex matrices and their inverses.